# Forward ASP.Net WebAPI request to another API

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to forward request from one API to another one like this:

```
protected Task<HttpResponseMessage> ForwardRequestToSomeApi()
{
    string forwardUri = "https://some.api" + Request.RequestUri.PathAndQuery;

    Request.Headers.Remove("Host");
    Request.RequestUri = new Uri(forwardUri);
    if (Request.Method == HttpMethod.Get)
    {
        Request.Content = null;
    }

    return new HttpClient().SendAsync(Request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
}
```

but when sending PUT request I get:

> Cannot close stream until all bytes are written.

Full exception info:

```
{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"An error occurred while sending the request.","ExceptionType":"System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException","StackTrace":"
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<CastToObject>d__1`1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__6.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__6.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__15.MoveNext()","InnerException":{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"The request was aborted: The request was canceled.","ExceptionType":"System.Net.WebException","StackTrace":"
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.CloseInternal(Boolean internalCall, Boolean aborting)\r\n
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.System.Net.ICloseEx.CloseEx(CloseExState closeState)\r\n
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)\r\n
   at System.IO.Stream.Close()\r\n
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.<>c__DisplayClass109_0.<GetRequestStreamCallback>b__0(Task task)","InnerException":{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Cannot close stream until all bytes are written.","ExceptionType":"System.IO.IOException","StackTrace":"
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.CloseInternal(Boolean internalCall, Boolean aborting)"}}}
```

Inner exception :

> IOException Message: "Cannot close stream until all bytes are
>   written." StackTrace:    at
>   System.Net.ConnectStream.CloseInternal(Boolean internalCall, Boolean
>   aborting)

**Update:**

Provided above code is fully working, the problem was how I attempted to use it. In my main API I had next webapi action:

```
[HttpPut]
public Task<HttpResponseMessage> Create(string id, Foo model)
{
   return ForwardRequestToSomeApi();
}
```

The problem here is I introduced the model in parameters, thanks to model binding request's content were being read and parsed into model, so when I forward request to another API I send request without content. The fix is to remove all parameters:

```
[HttpPut]
public Task<HttpResponseMessage> Create()
{
   return ForwardRequestToSomeApi();
}
```

Comment: You have sreturn instead of the return keyword. I am not sure that is the issue though.

Comment: sorry, copy-pasted

Comment: what does the inner exception say?

Comment: @user1666620, I have updated question with inner exception

Comment: Do you need to implement a reverse proxy?

Comment: @RomanMarusyk, partially yes, I want to forward a few actions of my api to another  my api, but not all

Comment: Did you try to create a new HttpRequestMessage from current Request and use it?

Comment: Create a new `HttpRequestMessage`, copy desired information over and make request.